# Can't create a variable in class that inherits from Atom api

Tags: python

When I inherit `Atom` from `atom.api`, I can not create a member variable.

What mechanism explains this?

```
from atom.api import Atom

class A:
    def init(self):
        self.var = 0

class B(Atom):
    def init(self):
        self.var = 0

a = A()
a.init()

b = B()
b.init()
```

When `b.init()` is executed, I get the error msg:

> AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'var'

Comment: I'd say its likely that atom being a `framework for creating memory efficient Python objects` is changing the underlying representation of the object itself. This probably causes ordinary assignment to be invalid. You should read the documentation for [atom](https://github.com/nucleic/atom) to see how it can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atom has overridden descriptors. They are responsible for the different behavior of the use of getters (`self.x`) and setters (`self.x = 42`). That's why you've got the error. For more information read:

1) About descriptors in Python: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html

2) About Atom framework: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/atom/0.3.6

Comment: Perhaps you could add the relevant part(s) of each link to your answer?

Answer (score 3):

Declare the variable like you would a static member of the class

```
class B(Atom):

    var = Range(low=0)

    def init(self):
        self.var = 0
```

It will then be considered by `atom` as a valid class field.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.